# How to have CSS animation only on click and not on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-material-design

I am using https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design in my project <strike>more specifically the checkbox</strike> this question is focused on the checkbox component, the entire library is being used in my project.

```
<label class="control-label">
  <div class="checkbox display-inline-block ">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" data-check="false" />
      <span class="ripple"></span>
      <span class="check"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
</label>
```

The problem is that the checkbox triggers an animation on page load and looks odd. The LESS code is https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/blob/master/less/_checkboxes.less#L88 and an example can be seen here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogmgRX

Does anyone know how to stop the animation for appearing on page load?

Comment: Don't trigger the init on page load?

Comment: I am using the entire project, I should have been more clear with my wording. If I don't init on page load other elements will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are instantiating it for the other elements in your DOM why not using something like:

```
$('label').click(function() { 
  $.material.checkbox();
});
```

See **[Example A](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEdPPp)**.

or maybe use CSS to disable initial animation if `checkbox` is not `checked`:

```
input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked) + .checkbox-material:before {
  -webkit-animation: none !important;
 -moz-animation: none !important;
 -o-animation: none !important;
 -ms-animation: none !important;
 animation: none !important;
}
```

See **[Example B](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azXOdo)**.

Comment: Good alternative but from a UI prospective this does not work. We need a checkbox in this location.

Comment: That is much closer and is something that we could consider but it completely removes the effect even after the page is loaded. The goal to have a plain checkbox (just a square) and only animate on click and not on page load or anything.

Comment: What if you edit [material.js](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/blob/master/dist/js/material.js) file and set the `options` for `checkbox` to `false`. This way you maybe then initiate it on click?

Comment: That will not stop the CSS animation from being triggered. My understanding is that the javascript only adds the element and that the CSS is what actually does the cool stuff, do I have it backwards?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73604/discussion-between-grady-d-and-cchacholiades).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed with [PR#996](https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/pull/996) and will be available from the next release `v.0.5.10`.

The fix was to make sure the animation is applied only to the elements having focus using the `:focus` pseudo selector as shown in this [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reQEMb)